# Target sibling elements in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dom

I have multiple button tags in a template that need to target the **ul** sibling below in order to apply style changes on click. How can I target the ul in the **showMore()** in the component?

```
        <button (click)="showMore()" class="show-more-btn"></button>
        <ul class="list-content">
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
        <button (click)="showMore()" class="show-more-btn"></button>
        <ul class="list-content">
            <li>List Item</li>
            <li>List Item</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you extract that to a separate component containing just a single button and list, then use e.g. `ViewChild`? You can then add as many as you like without having to repeat or overcomplicate the code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, This had helped solve my current problem. : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use template reference variable:

```
<button #butt1 (click)="butt1.showMore = !butt1.showMore;" class="show-more-btn">Show more</button>
<ul class="list-content" *ngIf="butt1.showMore">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
</ul>

<button #butt2 (click)="butt2.showMore = !butt2.showMore;" class="show-more-btn">Show more</button>
<ul class="list-content" *ngIf="butt2.showMore">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a object like this

```
uls = {
 ul1: false,
 ul2: false
};
```

And you can show ul on click like this

```
<button (click)="uls['ul1'] = true" class="show-more-btn"></button>
 <ul class="list-content" *ngIf="uls['ul1']">
   <li>List Item</li>
   <li>List Item</li>
 </ul>
 <button (click)="uls['ul2'] = true" class="show-more-btn"></button>
  <ul class="list-content" *ngIf="uls['ul2']">
   <li>List Item</li>
   <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
```

you can toggle as well like this

```
(click)="uls['ul1'] = !uls['ul1']"
```

it depends on you do it with function or directly in template like this I'll prefer this one if logic is simple.